# Clonezilla alternative on Windows

Tags: windows, hard-disk, disk-image

I am looking for a Clonezilla alternative. The only thing that I really need from a Clonezilla is deploying one whole disk image (1TB disk, with around 400GB of data) into 200-250 PC's I am changing then UUID with a script, so that is not a problem.

Is there something really good, but operated on Windows instead of Linux?

Unfortunately WDS is not the thing that I am looking for.